# How to obtain the same-sized-boxes?

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree

I want all the rectangle have the same size. What should I do?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east)
-- +(8pt,0)
|- (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=1.5cm}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree [.\node(root){S}; [.\node(np){NP}; [.\node(d){Det}; \node(t){the}; ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sat ]
[.PP [.P \node(o){on}; ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N \node(m){mat}; ] ] ] ] ]

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={align=left, anchor=center, font=\tiny\sffamily\bfseries,rectangle,draw}]
 \node[above= 2mm of t] (thenode) {FOURTH};
 \node[at =(thenode-|root)] {FIRST};
 \node[at =(thenode-|np)] {SECOND};
 \node[at =(thenode-|d)] {THIRD};
 \node[at =(thenode-|o)] {FIFTH};
 \node[at =(thenode-|m)] {SIXTH};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might add `text width=1cm` and `align=center` to the style declaration in the `scope`.

Comment: You really should consider taking a look at the package's documentation some time. You might be surprised: it includes examples and stuff of trees.

Answer (score 3):

I have

1. added the scope around tree and passed a style of `text width=\widthof{Det}` to the scope
2. added a style `minimum width=\widthof{FOURTH}` to the scope of upper labels
3. adjusted the level distance appropriately to accomodate these widths.

Code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east)
-- +(8pt,0)
|- (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=4.5em}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\begin{scope}[text width=\widthof{Det}]  %%<--- this
\Tree [.\node(root){S}; [.\node(np){NP}; [.\node(d){Det}; \node(t){the}; ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sat ]
[.PP [.P \node(o){on}; ]
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N \node(m){mat}; ] ] ] ] ]
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={align=left, anchor=center,
                             font=\tiny\sffamily\bfseries,rectangle,draw,
                             minimum width=\widthof{FOURTH}}]
 \node[above= 2mm of t] (thenode) {FOURTH};
 \node[at =(thenode-|root)] {FIRST};
 \node[at =(thenode-|np)] {SECOND};
 \node[at =(thenode-|d)] {THIRD};
 \node[at =(thenode-|o)] {FIFTH};
 \node[at =(thenode-|m)] {SIXTH};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's a spurious `minimum width={\widthof{Det}}` in the second scope.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks. I am sleep deprived :-) Corrected.